# GetLastWriteTime not accurate

Tags: .net, vb.net, file-io

I'm using a function to check on timestamps on files on remote computers. We have a LOT of computers.

What I am running into is a bit odd.

I run the query on a lot of computers. Time stamp on Computer26887 comes up as "1/4/2013 12:46:01 AM"
I UNC to that computer and check the file. In explorer, timestamp says "9/16/2013 11:23 AM" (an hour and a half ago) Hmmm....
Query again - same old, wrong, timestamp. I right-click on the file, go to properties and click "Details" in the properties window - "Date Modified 9/16/2013 11:23 AM"
Query again with the vb code - now it shows the right timestamp????

I've got hundreds of systems to go through and if I can't trust the data I'm getting, I have way too much work to do!!!

Any ideas?

**Update**
Basically, VB.NET is retrieving a cached version of the timestamp. The timestamp has been updated, but the cache still has the old timestamp.  How do I force the cache to update without manually opening the properties of the file in explorer??

```
Shared Function GetFileInfo(ByVal ComputerName As String, ByVal FiletoFind As String, info As String)
    Dim Ret As String = ""
    Dim targetfile = "\\" & ComputerName & "\" & FiletoFind
    Dim fi As FileInfo = New FileInfo(targetfile)
    If fi.Exists Then
        fi.refresh
        Select Case info
            Case Is = "Exists"
                Ret = fi.Exists.ToString
            Case Is = "Delete"
                fi.Delete()
                Ret = fi.Exists.ToString
            Case Is = "Created"
                Ret = fi.CreationTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
            Case Is = "Access"
                Ret = fi.LastAccessTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
            Case Is = "Mod"
                Ret = fi.LastWriteTime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")
        End Select
    Else
        Ret = "File Not Found"
    End If

    Ret = Ret.Replace(vbCrLf, "")
    Ret = Ret.Replace(vbCr, "")

    Return Ret

End Function
```

(I've also tried using `File` rather than `FileInfo`... check the post history)

**UPDATE**
As a test, I did a file check on a system using AutoIT3 code.  It returned accurate information.  After the AutoIT3 check, vb.net returned accurate timestamps.  So, what is the problem with vb.net that AutoIT3 does a better job??

```AutoIt
Func _timestampchk($path)
Dim $file,$astamp
$file = $path
$astamp = FileGetTime($file, 0, 0)
If IsArray($astamp) Then
    $stamp = $astamp[1] & "/" & $astamp[2] & "/" & $astamp[0] & " " & $astamp[3] & ":" & $astamp[4]
ElseIf $astamp = 0 Then
    $stamp = "File " & $path & " not Found"
Else
    $stamp = 0
EndIf
Return $stamp
EndFunc   ;==>_timestampchk
```

Comment: That does sound odd.  Is there any chance there is something going on with a difference in time zone?  By the way, just as a suggestion, you may want to consider using `MessageBox.Show` instead of `MsgBox`, `Ret.Replace` instead of `Replace`, and either making `info` an `Enum`, or breaking the method up into a separate method for each `Case`.

Comment: This is pretty normal, the file system has no obligation to constantly update the attribute while a process has the file opened.  There's a loud Note about it in the MSDN article for the property.  The only guarantee you have is that it is accurate when all processes close their handle to the file.  Something you'll have a hard time seeing from a remote machine.

Comment: @HansPassant - This is DAYS of not having accurate timestamp from vb .net - accurate in explorer, etc though.  These files are not constantly in use or open.  The timestamp should be available within at least 30 minutes.  It has been days on some - and I can 'force' a sync between explorer and whatever vb .net is looking at as described above.

Comment: Basically, VB.NET is retrieving a cached version of the timestamp.  How do I force the cache to update without manually opening the properties of the file in explorer??

Comment: Have you tried using a FileInfo object instead of the File methods? You can call .Refresh() on the former if it doesn't work initially. And have you thought about using a variable for `"\\" & ComputerName & "\" & FiletoFind` instead of typing it so many times? Note that your `<date>.ToString()` results will depend on the date settings on the computer where it's running - you might want to use `.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt")`.

Comment: I have to go with @AndrewMorton on this. The documentation in fact states `Calls must be made to Refresh before attempting to get the attribute information, or the information will be outdated.` Use [`FileSystemInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.getfileinfo.aspx) instead of `File`.

Comment: Is it definitely looking at the file you think it is looking at? (Also, you would need to use `Ret = Ret.Replace(vbCrLf, "")` etc. as the Replace method returns a new string rather than modifying an existing one, although I don't see how a `VbCrLf` or `VbCr` could be in the string with the code as shown.)

Comment: Please don't reply directly to commenters in your question body. Comments are a bit unstable and can be easily deleted, though it was good that you updated your post! I also fixed what I think was a small typo in your AutoIt script which was messing with the formatting (an unclosed string)

Comment: Okay, got it @Cybȫʁgϟ37 Thanks.
and at AndrewMorton - yes, it is looking at the right file.
Right now, I am calling the AutoIT3 .exe using System.Diagnostics.Process and passing the computer and file.  Pulling the info that way forces the .net cached info to update, so I get accurate info that apparently VB.NET can't do by itself, even with fi.Refresh() called twice... *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

Try FileSystem.GetFileInfo , as pointed by Andrew Morton, and  neoistheone

```
Dim information = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo("C:\MyLogFile.log")
information.Refresh()   ' Calls must be made to Refresh before attempting to get the attribute information, or the information will be outdated.
MsgBox("The file's full name is " & information.FullName & ".")
MsgBox("Last access time is " & information.LastAccessTime & ".")
MsgBox("The length is " & information.Length & ".")
```

---

Although documented, and rationale, it is a weird behavior. 
As curiosity, I would also try these code below to see if the problem also happens.
Try to use Windows API and see if it stills return the 'cached' data.

```
Declare Function GetFileTime Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hFile _ 
As Long, lpCreationTime As FILETIME, lpLastAccessTime _ 
As FILETIME, lpLastWriteTime As FILETIME) As Long
```

If this don´t solve, try to call the Open Properties window programatically, then read the date time information, and see if it solves the problem:

```
'#VBIDEUtils#***********************************************
' * Programmer Name  : Waty Thierry
' * Web Site         : www.geocities.com/ResearchTriangle/6311/
' * E-Mail           : waty.thierry@usa.net
' * Date             : 28/06/99
' * Time             : 13:16
' ********************************************************
' * Comments         : Showing the Properties dialog box
' *
' * This tip demonstrates how To use the Win32 API To
' * bring up the explorer properties
' * dialog box For a specified file.
' * This API Function has the same effect As Right
' * clicking On a file In Windows 95 And selecting properties.

' **************************************************
Option Explicit On

    Private Type SHELLEXECUTEINFO
        cbSize As Long
        fMask As Long
        hwnd As Long
        lpVerb As String
        lpFile As String
        lpParameters As String
        lpDirectory As String
        nShow As Long
        hInstApp As Long
        lpIDList As Long
        lpClass As String
        hkeyClass As Long
        dwHotKey As Long
        hIcon As Long
        hProcess As Long
    End Type

Private Const SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST = &HC
Private Const SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS = &H40
Private Const SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI = &H400

Private Declare Function ShellExecuteEX Lib "shell32.dll" Alias _
   "ShellExecuteEx" (SEI As SHELLEXECUTEINFO) As Long

Public Function ShowProps(FileName As String, _
   OwnerhWnd As Long) As Boolean

    'USAGE:
    'To show the properties dialog box of "c:\autoexec.bat", use the following code:
    'Call ShowProps("c:\autoexec.bat", Me.hwnd)
    'Function will return false if
    'property windows can't be shown for
    'any reason (e.g., invalid file or Ownerhwnd)


    On Error Resume Next
    Dim SEI As SHELLEXECUTEINFO
    Dim r As Long
    With SEI
        .cbSize = Len(SEI)
        .fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS Or _
         SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST Or SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI
        .hwnd = OwnerhWnd
        .lpVerb = "properties"
        .lpFile = FileName
        .lpParameters = vbNullChar
        .lpDirectory = vbNullChar
        .nShow = 0
        .hInstApp = 0
        .lpIDList = 0
    End With
    r = ShellExecuteEX(SEI)
    ShowProps = r
End Function
```